# ERROR org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport - SASL negotiation failure javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed

Tags: java, hive, kerberos

did try write hive client that working with Kerberos.

IDEA did work in OS Windows 2012 R2,
I did prepare folder with Hadoop files (did copy from there [winutils](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils)) to local folder

```
c:\hadoop
```

After did set evironment

```
  set HOME_HADOOP=c:\hadoop
```

Then did write this code

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
    try {
        org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration conf = new     org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration();
        conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos");
        UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
        UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("testuser@DOM.COM", "C:\\Servers\\Repository\\Templates\\HiveClient\\src\\main\\resources\\testuser.keytab");
        Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
        System.out.println("getting connection");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://rnd-server02:10010/default;principal=testuser@DOM.COM");
        System.out.println("Connected");
        con.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Did try to excute and did return error

```
00:49:05.950 [main] ERROR org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport - SASL negotiation failure
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed
    at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:211) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.handleSaslStartMessage(TSaslClientTransport.java:94) ~[libthrift-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:271) [libthrift-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
    at
```

How solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have the keytab at the location specified in the code?

Comment: I did have the keytab at the location by path: C:\\Servers\\Repository\\Templates\\HiveClient\\src\\main\\resources\\testuser.keytab

Comment: Enable Kerberos debugging by the Java debug flag.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382056